# Open Modal from Rails Partial and Pass Partial Param

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a partial that has a table, one row for each record. When I click on an image in the row, I would like to open a modal and have the modal have access to the record. I'm passing in the records to the partial like this:

```
<%= render :partial => "record", :collection => @records, as: :records %>
```

In the modal, I would like to have access to the record so I can use the records attributes to populate parts of the modal. Is this possible? How can I make the modal have access to the records attributes?

**EDIT:** The modal lives on the index view (it is hidden with css), so the working path is index -> partial -> click image -> index view (modal shown with jQuery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AJAX to retrieve the data and render the modal at the point you click on the image. Assuming you are just viewing the data this will be something like:

```
<%= link_to record_path(record), remote: true do %>
   <%= image_tag "image.jpg" %>
<% end %>
```

On clicking on the image it will then route to the RecordsController::show action where you can retrieve the record and render it in your modal in show.js.erb